# How to do a live search on a million rows of data using angular JS and JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I have been using angularJS and JSON.
This is how I got the data into the view.

```
@{
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    var jsonModel = serializer.Serialize(Model.PartsCollection);
}
<script>
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('partsController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.parts = @Html.Raw(jsonModel);
</script>
```

I am trying to filter the data in json using filter directive in angularJS

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="partsController">
  Enter part Number: <input type="text" ng-model="mypart" />

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in parts | filter:mypart">
            {{x}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I try to run this, CPU and Memory utilization goes to almost 100% and nothing happens. It would be amazing if anyone has put any thought into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pagination, split your data into pages and let a service do the filter for you using ng-change on the input value.

displaying more the 1M rows is quite a lot, so there will be a very long scroll to the end of the page.

when you use pagination you can decrease the amount of row that exists in the DOM

Comment: I don't need to display the whole 1 million rows. When the user types into the text field he should get all the similar data at the bottom of the text box.

Comment: but the problem is when the input term is blank you display all the rows... that why your cpu increases so much...

Answer (score 0):

Iteration over 1 million data items can be an intensive task... there are obvious ways to reduce the client resources by doing a sort on the server or even in your sql query (if you query the db)

Because you've asked specifically for angular, the solution is as follows.

Let's say a sample JSON looks as follows:

```
{
   Part_Name: "Cog",
   Part_Number: 1
}
```

Then your `ng-repeat` should look like below:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in parts | filter:{Part_Number: mypart}">
   {{x}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Send backend request with passing query params using input tag.